# Do I use async.js in a bad way

Tags: async.js

I think I must be using Async in a bad way. The only way I managed to do it using Async is this:

```
        var email = request.payload.email;

        async.waterfall([
            function (callback) {
                async.parallel({
                    title    : function (callbackWaterfall) {
                        async.waterfall([
                            async.apply(UserDao.findUser, email),
                            createTripTitle
                        ], callbackWaterfall)
                    },
                    tripCount: TripDao.countTrips
                }, callback)
            },
            function (results, callback) {
                TripDao.createTrip(results.title, results.tripCount, callback);
            }
        ], function (err, trip) {
            resCallback(err, request, response, trip);
        });
```

It removes the callback hell but still it is HELL to read it.

In a synchronous code I would have this simple code snippet:

```
var email = request.payload.email,
    user = UserDao.findUser(email),
    title = getTitle(user),
    tripCount = countMyTrips(),
    newTrip = TripDao.createTrip(title, tripCount);
```

Is there a way how to simplify my async.js example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use async.auto

```
var email = request.payload.email

async.auto({
    user: async.apply(UserDao.findUser, email),
    title: ['user', function (results, callback){
        getTitle(results['user'], callback)
    }],
    tripCount: async.apply(countMyTrips),
    newTrip: ['title', tripCount', function (results, callback) {
        TripDao.createTrip(results['title'], results['tripCount'], callback);
    }]
}, function (err, results) {
    //all done
})
```

Comment: Thank you, Golak, you opened my eyes! You'll definitelly deserve the reward. As soon as I can raise it I will give it to you. I finally solved it using `autoInject` which add a little more readability.

Comment: @zatziky you have to start a bounty on this question and then award the answer manually

Comment: Bounty started. In 24 hours it can be rewarded.

Answer (score 1):

Due to @GolakSarangi and his `async.auto` solution I discovered `async.autoInject` that I find even more readable.

Here is my solution:

```
async.autoInject({
            tripCount: TripDao.countTrips,
            email: function(callback){ callback(null /*err*/, request.payload.email) },
            user: ['email', UserDao.findUser],
            title: ['user', createTripTitle],
            trip: ['title', 'tripCount', TripDao.createTrip]
        }, ['trip', function(err, trip){
            resCallback(err, request, response, trip);
        }]);
```